# maven cargo plugin configuration for Jboss as 7.1.0

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, maven-cargo

I am trying to configure the maven cargo plugin for deployment on existing jboss 7.1.0 on my local machine. I am able to start the server by
mvn cargo :run command. It is using the jboss-modules.jar to start the server. I want to configure it in such a way that it executes the standalone.bat inside the bin to start the server. I have my datasource configured in standalone.conf.bat and hence I need to execute the standalone.bat to start and deploy the war.. My configuration looks like this..

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
        <wait>true</wait>
            <container>
                 <containerId>jboss7x</containerId>
                 <home>C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/</home>

            </container>
              <configuration>
                <type>existing</type>

                <home>C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone</home>
              </configuration>
         </configuration>
```

Is there any property in cargo configuration to set to call the standalone.bat to start the server?

Thanks,

Comment: As an alternative to the cargo-maven-plugin you might want to have a look at the jboss-as-maven-plugin (https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin). This runs fine in our project.

Comment: @Riggs - yeah. jboss-as-maven plugin cannot be used to start the server I think.. it is just used to deploy the artifact to the running server... So.. tht doesn't help in my case... :(

Comment: @sampath did you got it working?
I have a problem like this too.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit outdated, however with the current release of JBoss Maven plugin it is actually possible to start and stop the application server using mvn jboss-as:start and mvn jboss-as:shutdown commands. I have added a [Maven JBoss tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-maven/maven-jboss-as-7-plugin-tutorial) time ago describing exactly this.